# Extending many User Profile in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend the auth User model class of Django. I have one problem and one question. Here is my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BaseUser(models.Model):
    """
    some common fields
    """

    user = User.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Base User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Base Users'

User.profile = property(lambda u: BaseUser.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])


class Client(BaseUser):
    """
    some client specific fields
    """
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Client'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clients'


class Owner(BaseUser):
    """
    some owner specific fields
    """

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Owner'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Owners'


class Driver(BaseUser):
    """
    some driver specific fields
    """

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Driver'
        verbose_name_plural : 'Drivers'
```

My problem: When I go to the admin site to check Clients for example, I am getting this error (the app is called etaxi_prod):

```
column etaxi_prod_baseuser.id does not exist
```

What is going on here?

My question, if the above solution is found: What should I do to make BaseUser class abstract in order to only deal with Client, Driver and Owner as user auth classes?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.5.3